# Why doesn't my name show when I send a text message?

Tags: iphone

When I send a text message, my name does not show up to the recipient; only my number.
Is there some way to change the settings to have my name show up instead of the number?

Answer (score 2):

The recipient would have to have your contact added in order to associate your name to your number.

Sometimes the format of the number would matter: it's better if the recipient copies the number as it appears when you send him an SMS.